# Problema em receber o retorno de um objeto

Tags: ios, orientação-a-objetos, objective-c

Criei uma classe para baixar dados de um web service.
E faço os seguintes passos para teste:

Instancio a classe de download em viewDidLoad de ViewController e depois executo o método, como no código abaixo:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        GDRequestURL* getData = [[GDRequestURL alloc]init];
        [getData getDataFromURL];
        // Aqui instancio um objeto para receber o retorno.
        NSMutableArray* restultado = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        //NEste ponto faço a execução para receber o retorno dos dados.
        restultado = [getData retornaResultado];
  }
```

Porém o retorno é nil.

Comment: Sem ver a classe `GDRequestURL` não dá pra saber o que pode estar acontecendo.

Comment: @TiagoAmara, crie uma resposta com código para a sua própria pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver!! O problema estava no momento que eu estava realizando o retorno dos dados para a variável resultado. Eu estava fazendo isso antes de getData realizar o request dos dados. Então criei uma variável global da classe GDRequestURL em ViewContronller, e criei um botão de ação para ser usado para teste, e executar a ação de retornar os dados apos a conclusão da solicitação. Ficando deste modo:

ViewController.h

```
...

@interface ViewController{

GDRequestURL* getData;

}
```

ViewController.m

```
    ...
     - (void)viewDidLoad {
            [super viewDidLoad];


            getData = [[GDRequestURL alloc]init];
            [getData getDataFromURL];

      }

...

-(IBAction)retornaValores{

         // Aqui instancio um objeto para receber o retorno.
            NSMutableArray* restultado = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

            //NEste ponto faço a execução para receber o retorno dos dados.
            restultado = [getData retornaResultado];

...

}
```

Comment: Sua resposta não faz sentido. O escopo do método no qual uma mensagem é enviada não deveria alterar a corretude do programa. Mostre sua classe `GDRequestURL` para que possamos aprimorá-la utilizando requisições assíncronas.

Comment: Você tocou no foco do problema!
 Como a requisição já ocorre de maneira assíncrona eu estava instanciando e executando o método na inicialização da classe, e isso faria com que o envio da mensagem ocorresse antes do fim da requisição dos dados, retornando um objeto vazio.

 Quando instancio o objeto fora da inicialização, e tornando ele com um escopo geral, ele eu posso enviar a mensagem a qualquer momento. Também coloquei um método para permitir que o objeto seja retornado, somente após o termino da requisição.

Comment: Sim, se fosse síncrona seu código da pergunta estaria funcionando, o que eu estou dizendo é que é necessário adicionar um meio de notificar sua classe que a requisição acabou. Pode-se usar um completion handler na requisição ou então a adoção de um protocolo formal como um Delegate. Esse mecanismo deve ser adicionado em `GDRequestURL` se não estiver presente, por isso pedi para vê-la.

Comment: Ah sim, mas ta ok agora... eu criei um mecanismo para verificar isso. Mas dentro do que foi perguntado essa alteração funcionou. Por isso que expliquei no inicio da resposta: "...eu estava realizando o retorno dos dados para a variável resultado. Eu estava fazendo isso antes de getData realizar o request dos dados.".

Comment: Que bom que deu certo, então :)